# Drawing subfigure

Tags: subfloats

I want to put two figures beside each other... I tried but I encountered to some errors. I have used these packages:

```
\usepackage{subfloat}‎
‎\usepackage{subfigure}‎

‎\begin{figure}[!htb]‎‎
‎‎\centering‎‎
‎\subfigure[]{‎
‎\includegraphics[width=.3]{fig1.eps}‎‎‎
}
‎\hspace*{1mm}‎
‎\subfigure[]{‎
‎\includegraphics[width=.3]{fig2.eps}‎‎
}‎
‎\caption{hi}‎‎‎
‎\end{figure}‎
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, notice that your code doesn't compile because it is plenty of spurious characters U+200E (LEFT-TO-RIGHT MARK).

Moreover, the package `subfigure` is deprecated.

The easiest replacement is the `subcaption` package. Here is how you can achieve your requirements with it.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[!htb]
\centering
\begin{subfigure}[b]{.3\linewidth}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{fig1.eps}
\end{subfigure}%
\hspace*{1mm}%
\begin{subfigure}[b]{.3\linewidth}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-b}
\end{subfigure}
\caption{Hi}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Output

[image]

If you want empty captions for the subfigures use `\caption{}` inside the `subfigure`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[!htb]
\centering
\begin{subfigure}[b]{.3\linewidth}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{fig1.eps}
\caption{}
\end{subfigure}%
\hspace*{1mm}%
\begin{subfigure}[b]{.3\linewidth}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-b}
\caption{}
\end{subfigure}
\caption{Hi}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: why my figures appear as a black picture?

Comment: @hamed Change `\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}` to `\usepackage{graphicx}` in your document

Comment: wwwwoooowww... I sincerely appreciate u my friend...thanks alot...

Comment: @hamed Glad it helped you. :-)